# UV problem with Soda Can (Maya Beginner)

Tags: 3d, texture, maya

Hi all I am making a Coke Can in Maya. I want to UV map it so I can add the texture of different sodas to it.

I thought i was careful to use only one mesh and not have it all split into different pieces, with no intersecting edges etc.

In the UV editor, the top part of my can is still twisted into a circle and basically unusable:

[image]

It is hard to see but in the Perspective View there you can see I've highlighted a full 'ring' of edges. In the UV Window the highlight is one of those strands in the circle.

The area affected by this problem seems to be the part that I extruded and scaled down as to make the slope in the can.

Is this fixable? Or should i start over again (or cut the top off and go again)?

I understand this isn't easy to see the fix from the screenshot, please ask me if you need more info or if there is something I can try to fix it. (Also note: This is my first UV'ing project for a very long time)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You should Revolve a nurbs surface.

Comment: I did not use NURBS. Are you telling me I should be using them to unwrap the UV or that I should use it to make the can itself? (thanks for the help btw)

Comment: If you make it as a revolved nurbs surface then you have a perfect uv. Its also conceptuallty simpler to model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if that helps but in C4D you can use projection like this:

[image]

It maps the image on a cylinder around the object and projects it. Maybe Maya can do something similar.

Comment: Yes but its not really productive way to work its much much more productive to revolve a curve. As it generates a better model, you get even better uvs and is less work.

Comment: @joojaa I think the question is not about how to model but rather how to apply the label easily. My answer is an easy way to apply a label. When it comes to good UVs, I have no clue.

Comment: Well user specifically asks for uv mapping. But sure, it depends on the usecase. You can not separate uv mapping from modeling as it is the same thing.

Comment: @joojaa The same thing?!? UV maps simply describe which areas of the texture go on the model surface. You can have very good topology and a very unusable UV. For example I clicked some automatic thing in C4D. I got something similar to the OP. 4 different walls with some circular parts for the bottom, good luck with that map.

Comment: yes uv mapping is a modeling task. So doing uv maps is indeed part of modeling. Yes you can do it badly. My point is had the user chosen a different modeling tool the would have gotten a perfect uv map for free since they would have had a u along a line so when the sweep it they would get a perfect uv map. Dont start with a square or cylinder  dont extrude do a revolve. Same thing works in cinema 4D too. Its far less work takes aboit a minute to do from scratch.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer @Komental . I have indeed fiddled about with similar settings since posting the question. However in the end I started again and for some reason the 'auto UV' worked for me. It didnt allow me to upvote your answer because I am new :|